# MongoDB - aggregation sort with group doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query in Ruby on Rails for mongo:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$match' => {
          :user_id => '12345',
          :type => "view"
        }
    },
    {
        '$group' => {
            :_id => '$room_id',
            'message_time' => {'$first' => '$message_time'},
            'message_text' => {'$first' => '$message_text'},
            'from' => {'$first' => '$message.from_user'}
        }
    },
    {
      '$skip' => 0
    },
    {
      '$limit' => 10
    },
    {'$sort' => {"message_time" => -1}}
  ])
```

Example message:

```
{
  "_id":"5705248b6cd7b15aca000018", 
  "message_time":"2016-08-23T16:57:12Z",
  "message_text":"Example text",
  "from": {
    "id":"1234",
    "name":"Test user",
    "first_name":"Test"
  }
  ,"room_id":"1231231231"
}
```

In message time I have value like: `2016-08-22T12:49:29Z`
Even if I change sort to `message_text` it doesn't sort properly.

Any ideas how to sort this? I was trying with putting everything from `group` into `_id` field and then sort by`_id.message_time` but still Its returning the wrong result.

Comment: how is `message_time` stored in the database? Can we see an example message document?  Is that the collection you're querying on?

Comment: You don't say what's not working about the sort, but I would guess that you're looking for the most recent messages, so you need to move your `$sort` before the `$skip` and `$limit` (or even before the `$group`) so that the skip and limit are applied after the sort, not before it. Is that the problem you're seeing?

Comment: ok, message_time is stored as a Time class. I was trying put $sort before skip and limit, even before group or even match but it's sorting strange. For example i have times in that order (started from first result):  - 2016-08-23T16:57:12Z,  
- 2016-08-22T12:13:02Z,  
- 2016-08-22T11:42:51Z,  
- 2016-08-22T12:37:28Z,  
- 2016-08-22T12:46:13Z,  
- 2016-08-23T10:46:09Z  
Don't know why it's sorting that way.